# OpenCL returning nan after changing device

Tags: macos, opencl

I'm trying to run a simple OpenCL program that adds two vectors in individual buffers, and stores the result in the third buffer. I'm trying to run it on a MacBook Pro with a discrete GPU. The AMD GPU is (through the `clGetDeviceInfo` function), second in the device list with the integrated GPU being the first. It works correctly with the integrated GPU. But when I modify the command queue initialisation to the following:

```
cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_list[1], 0, &clStatus);
```

It returns NaN values in the output. If I use `device_list[0]`, it works. I only changed the command queue initialisation. So how do I guarantee that I use the discrete GPU without issue?

Comment: Could you please post the complete source code?

Comment: It's fine. It works now; my kernel code had an issue where I was using using sigmoids with a big scale factor. That caused NaNs. Thank you for your assistance still.